# Describing a custom device on LPC to the Linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, x86, x86-64, acpi

I have a custom multi-function device hanging off an LPC bus. Works fine with hardcoded addresses in a force-loaded kernel module, but longer-term I'd like to move towards per-function modules (there are about ten miscellaneous functions in there).

The recommended way seems to be to create a module that checks if the hardware is there and has the right version, then creates device tree entries for the functions, causing hot-plug events for the subunits.

1. Does this work on x86_64?
2. Does that give me any advantage over a single force-loaded module, given that I still need to load the detection module?
3. Does it make sense to instead create an ACPI table describing the device, and pass that to the kernel from the BIOS?

Comment: Can you really use #3? ACPI tables are created by the BIOS, do you control it? I think you can "synthesize" a table by calling the appropriate functions of the kernel, but you probably want to define a *device* and not a table. But wouldn't it require to add code to the ACPI driver? or is your device standard? About #2, if I understand you correctly, your device is not PnP, it uses fixed addresses, right? LPC has no PnP mechanism. If you don't need PnP, maybe a simple module is enough but I'm not super-versed on the Linux device discovery mechanism. Regarding #1, I don't think it's relevant.

Comment: @MargaretBloom, I could add an ACPI SSDT from a SysPrep entry in the UEFI Boot Manager, so that would probably work, although it is *complicated*. The device isn't PnP, which is why I have to force-load a module currently. If device tree entries work on PCs that have ACPI as platform bus enumeration and that doesn't require booting from OpenFirmware or at least importing an FDT, that is a viable option that would be a lot less complicated. :)

Comment: The proper way is #3.

Comment: @SimonRichter Sorry, I've brushed up on the ACPI spec. So with #3, your idea is to load an SSDT with a definition block for your device and make the kernel match your driver by _HID. That seems the cleaner approach as 0andriy pointed out but it would require a SysPrep app and may not work if the table is already present (correct me if I'm wrong). Given that you mention FDT and ACPI, I suppose you are working on an embedded system based on x86? [DT and ACPI overlap and not everyone agree on which to use](https://xenproject.org/2013/12/03/xen-on-arm-and-the-device-tree-vs-acpi-debate/) ...

Comment: ... but personally I see ACPI more idiomatic on x86. I don't know if it is fully "accepted" on ARM too nowadays. In either case, having the device configuration separated from the driver is the way to go, be it an ACPI definition block or a DTS :) I think if you enable DTs in the kernel, they should work even on ACPI systems. I guess the union of the device sets is taken.

Comment: [This question seems to imply the kernel can use both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31875450/linux-device-tree-to-acpi-driver) through different matching lists. So it's a matter of consistency. Sorry for the spam :))

Comment: @MargaretBloom, There are two ways to give ACPI to the Linux OS nowadays: override (when you completely substitute existing table with a new one) and thru SSDT (something similar to DT overlays). JFYI: there is interesting (mostly for DIY and IoT makers) project how to connect devices to ACPI enabled boards: https://github.com/westeri/meta-acpi

Comment: @0andriy but couldn't the SSDT table be also defined by the BIOS? Or this never happens?

Comment: @MargaretBloom, yes it can. IIRC ACPICA supports 64 (or 256?) SSDTs.

Comment: Thanks @0andriy, It never occurred to me that there could be *more than one SSDT*. It seems that some UEFI implementation of the ACPI protocol may not load tables with duplicate signatures, though.

Comment: @MargaretBloom, it seems that those implementations are not good. Nowadays EFI can also provide an SSDT (in a variable with predefined GUID). There is no limit by signatures per se, the point of care is to avoid data collisions (same devices / methods / variables / objects in different SSDTs).